# Chrome only clears storage on closing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, offline-caching

I am trying to cache files using the caching api our use case requires us to cache about 50 - 100Mb.

I use a web worker to sync the files and a service worker to serve them. And when a new version is available i want to delete all old files and sync the new ones.

to clear the whole cache i use:

```
# (typescript)
return caches.delete(CacheFileStorage.CACHE_KEY).then(() => ...);
```

And to delete an individual file i use (where `this.cache` is the instance returned from `caches.open()`:

```
# (typescript)
return this.cache.delete(filename).then(() => ...);
```

It looks like the cache is cleared, but `storage.estimate` isn't reset until the tab is closed. The problem with this is that the application is running in a controlled environment and will be running for multiple months (without refreshing).

clearing using devtools does reset the quota immediately so i checked the code in github but this looks like an api not available to me [(DOMStorageModel.js)](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/ea371f55d17d9b5909785c7c636be866f44cc352/front_end/resources/DOMStorageModel.js).

So my question, does any one have experience with this, am i doing something wrong or will chrome reset this quota on regular intervals / when the quota is reached?

Comment: It may be an intended behavior or a bug in the browser. Check https://crbug.com and report the issue if it's not there.

Comment: Thank you, i reported it here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=816433&can=2&q=component%3ABlink%3EStorage%3ECacheStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed in version 65.0.3320.0 (currently in beta branch).
I've tested it, and this fix solved my problem!

(also see: [Issue 801024](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801024))